# PySimpleGUI - Column won't update

Tags: python, user-interface, pysimplegui

Trying to build a simple window with PySimpleGUI. I want to have a list of lines with info about videos that are stored in a list. This is my code:

```
layout = [
    [sg.Text("Clique para iniciar:")],
    *[[sg.Button(k)] for k in botoes],
    # [sg.Column([[sg.Text('Passos')]], key = 'CONTAINER_STATUS')],
    [sg.Text('Índice Vídeo Selecionado:'), sg.In(key=0), sg.In(key=1, enable_events=True)],
    # [sg.Text('Status Vídeos: ')],
    [sg.Text('Vídeo'), sg.Text('Status Vídeo'), sg.Text('Status Thumbnail')],
    [sg.Column([[sg.Text('test'), sg.Text('test2')],[sg.Text('test3'),sg.Text('test4')]], key='CONTAINER_VIDEOS', size= (50, 50))],
]

window = sg.Window("Iniciar Processamento de Vídeo", layout)

def get_layout_video(video):
    status = video.status.name if video.status is not None else ''
    status_thumb = video.thumbnail.status.name if video.thumbnail.status is not None else ''
    try:
        layout = [
            sg.Text(video.id_video_original), sg.Text(status), sg.Text(status_thumb)
        ]
        return layout
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return []

# Create an event loop
print('Running')
while True:
    event, values = window.read()

    window["CONTAINER_VIDEOS"].update([get_layout_video(v) for v in sessao.videos] if len(sessao.videos) > 0 else [[]])
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
```

I have debugged with several different possibilities. The events that cause the list to change were omitted, but I'm sure they work. The result of `get_layout_video` is correct, it looks like a normal layout for the column, similar to the test one. I have also tried an empty list of lists `[[]]`, but nothing happens. The Column simply keeps it's original value.  When I try another type of element (such as sg.Text) it works correctly, updating the value. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: check method `update` of `Column` in https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/call%20reference/#column-element, there's only one option `visible`, no layout update.

Comment: I see. Thank you. Do you know what kind of Element I should use to achieve what I'm trying to do? Adding a dynamic number of lines to the layout of my window.

Comment: There're some ways to go, but no dynamic layout. For examples, new window, visible/invisible elements or `sg.Column` with `sg.pin`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find how to directly change the column of the sg, but I made an update function that will solve your problem, it will close and recreate the sg window with the updated column.

Here is the code for the update column.

```
def update_column():
global window
layout = [
    [sg.Text("Clique para iniciar:")],
    *[[sg.Button(k)] for k in botoes],
    # [sg.Column([[sg.Text('Passos')]], key = 'CONTAINER_STATUS')],
    [sg.Text('Índice Vídeo Selecionado:'), sg.In(key=0), sg.In(key=1, enable_events=True)],
    # [sg.Text('Status Vídeos: ')],
    [sg.Text('Vídeo'), sg.Text('Status Vídeo'), sg.Text('Status Thumbnail')],
    [sg.Column([get_layout_video(v) for v in sessao.videos] if len(sessao.videos) > 0 else [[]], key='CONTAINER_VIDEOS', size=(150, 50))],
]
window.close()
window = sg.Window("Iniciar Processamento de Vídeo", layout)

print('Running')
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    update_column()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
```

some photos:

[before I click anything:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmNZH.png)

[after I click something:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5xiH.png)

Comment: Thank you! I guess this does the trick. I was afraid doing this kind of thing would have other unintended effects. Actually, does this cause the inputs to become blank, right? Can't test it right now, but when I have the time I will give some more feedback and choose this answer if it works.

Comment: You can always save the inputs before closing and reopening the window, and then you can put the inputs back.

Or you can call this update_column function at the end of your calculation, it depends on your needs.

Let me know if there is anything else you need help with.

Comment: Thanks for the help, mate. I ended up deciding to go a different route, since I figured in my use case it would be simpler than storing the inputs, so I have a fixed number of lines in the column, and update the text of those lines to get the intended result. Thanks for your effort.